# Does there exist an upper bound for $\|\tanh{(x)}-\tanh{(y)}\|$ smaller than $2\sqrt{n}$, where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: inequality, vectors

I wish to find a bound over the expression $\|\tanh{(x)}-\tanh{(y)}\|$, where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. This is more like proof verification. I have already found a bound, but I am interested to know if my reasoning is correct or if one can find an even tighter bound over this quantity?
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\|\tanh{(x)}-\tanh{(y)}\| &\leq  \|\tanh{(x)}\|\\
&+\|\tanh{(y)}\|
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Now,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\|\tanh{(x)}\| &\leq \sqrt{1^2+1^2+...+1^2(n~ times)} \\
\|\tanh{(x)}\|&\leq \sqrt{n}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Similarly, $\|\tanh{(y)}\| \leq \sqrt{n}$, therefore,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\|\tanh{(x)}-\tanh{(y)}\| &\leq \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n} \\
&\leq 2\sqrt{n}
\end{split}    
\end{equation}
Is my reasoning correct? Is it possible to find an even tighter bound over $\|\tanh{(x)}-\tanh{(y)}\|$?

Comment: I assume $\tanh$ of a vector is just the normal $\tanh$ function applied componentwise?

Comment: What does $\tanh x$ mean for $x \in \Bbb R^n$, $n \neq 1$?

Comment: Yes that is correct, $\tanh(x)$ and  $\tanh(y)$ implies $\tanh$ applied to each component of vector $x,y$. and n can be anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard to see that $\tanh$ is $1$-Lipschitz, so you have
\begin{align*}
\|\tanh(x)-\tanh(y)\|^2&=\sum_{i=1}^n \vert \tanh(x_i)-\tanh(y_i)\vert^2\\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \min(\vert x_i-y_i\vert,2)^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \min(\vert x_i-y_i\vert^2,4).
\end{align*}
Taking squareroots gives you a tighter bound than what you have.

Comment: Hi Jason, if we assume n=1, then in that case, this quantity is bounded by 2. So, in a n-dimensional setting, wont it be $2\sqrt{n}$? Just curious. Also, I did not quite understand how you went from step 1 to 2. I mean, isnt $|\tanh{x_i}-\tanh{y_i}|^2 \leq 4$? Please shed some more light. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: The point is that because $\tanh$ is $1$-Lipschitz, $\vert \tanh(x_i)-\tanh(y_i)\vert\leq \vert x_i-y_i\vert$. But because $\tanh(z)\in [-1,1]$, it is also upper bounded by $2$, as you say. What I wrote just takes the better of these.